# is the saying "official website" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage

many people encountered a fake website, especially when download some software.

so, we need to examine whether a website is the official website for that software sometimes.

is the saying "official website" idiomatic?

Comment: As a learner: Yup that's the most idiomatic construction IMHO.

Comment: Also consider *authentic* or *genuine*. You can have website that are not *official* but still not *fake*, such as fansites that are not endorsed by the celebrity.